# Intermittently missing Wicket session flash messages

Tags: java, google-app-engine, wicket

My Apache Wicket web application is deployed on Google App Engine for Java (GAE/J).

An issue is that sometimes a session flash message either does not appear when it should, or else it appears but is empty.

For example, instead of the expected:

```
<ul class="feedbackPanel">
  <li class="feedbackPanelINFO">
    <span class="feedbackPanelINFO">Thanks for taking the trouble to log off.</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

I sometimes get

```
<ul class="feedbackPanel">
  <li class="feedbackPanelINFO">
    <span class="feedbackPanelINFO"></span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

instead (when the informational flash message string submitted is not empty).

This problem might be caused by a failure to interpret the user's web session properly. Has anyone else encountered this problem?

My software environment

- Apache Wicket: 6.5.0
- GAE/J:         1.7.4
- Java:          1.6.0_37

**Update**

I believe that I have isolated the occurrences of this problem. This problem only occurs when a new GAE/J instance is spun up via an (automatic) warm-up request to handle the request, the response to which is served by this newly-warmed-up instance.

It might be possible that a newly-warmed-up instance is not reading the user's Wicket session object properly, and thus not finding and rendering any pending session flash message.

Comment: I note the Wicket bug WICKET-5165 (Session should be bound when adding messages to it) at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-5165 has been fixed in Wicket 6.9.0. I'll see when the time comes whether this fixes my issue in production.

Comment: Nope. This issue remains for me.