# ComponentNotFoundException on GAE/J in production but not on the dev app server

Tags: java, google-app-engine, wicket

### Introduction

I get this issue in a deterministic manner which is helpful, but the unhelpful bit is that the issue occurs in production using Google App Engine for Java (GA/J) but does not occur using the GAE/J dev app server on my local machine.

### My problem

I have the following page classes, all descended from WebPage:

```
PageHome      (stateless)
PageBrowse    (stateless)
PageSearch    (stateful)
PageImages    (stateful)
PageImage     (stateful)
```

### Path usage in development

I navigate through the path, and all images are shown successfully:

```
PageHome
  |
  |
  V
PageBrowse or PageSearch
  |
  |
  V
PageImages    (all images are shown)
  |
  |
  V
PageImage     (the image is shown)
  |
  |
  V
PageImages    (all images are shown)
  |
  |
  V
PageBrowse or PageSearch (respectively)
  |
  |
  V
PageHome
```

### Path usage in production - browsing

I attempt to navigate through the same "browse" path as in development with the following results:

```
PageHome
  |
  |
  V
PageBrowse
  |
  |
  V
PageImages    (all images are shown)
  |
  |
  V
PageImage     (image showing fails - the framework attempts to show the image component from PageImages instead of from PageImage)
  |
  |
  V
PageBrowse    (the submit button goes directly to this page instead of to PageImages)
  |
  |
  V
PageHome
```

### Path usage in production - searching

I attempt to navigate through the same "search" path as in development with the following results:

```
PageHome
  |
  |
  V
PageSearch
  |
  |
  V
PageImages    (all images are shown)
  |
  |
  V
PageImage     (the image is shown)
  |
  |
  V
PageImages    (the showing of all images fails - the framework attempts to show the image components from PageImage instead of from PageImages)
  |
  |
  V
PageImages    (the submit button goes to this page again instead of to PageSearch, with failed image showing)
  |
  |
  V
PageImages    (...)
```

### Tentative conclusions

Because this issue arises in GAE/J production but not on the GAE/J dev app server, this issue may result from how the session is stored by the different web servers. This might be related to my StackOverflow post "Intermittently missing Wicket session flash messages" at [Intermittently missing Wicket session flash messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14344740/intermittently-missing-wicket-session-flash-messages).

In the "browse" path, when moving from PageImages to PageImage using code of the form

```
PageImage pgNext = new PageImage(...);
setResponsePage(pgNext);
```

the framework appears to behave on PageImage as if it were still on PageImages: it tries to get its image component from PageImages, and its form submission event handler executes as the same in PageImages would do.

Similarly, in the "search" path, when moving from PageImage to PageImages using code of the form

```
PageImages pgNext = new PageImages(...);
setResponsePage(pgNext);
```

the framework appears to behave on PageImages as if it were still on PageImage: it tries to get its image components from PageImage, and its form submission event handler executes as the same in PageImage would do.

Perhaps this issue arises at different pages in the two paths because PageBrowse is stateless whereas PageSearch is stateful.

### Conclusion

Does anyone have any bright ideas or comments?

### Software environment

**Production**

```
Web server:       Google App Engine for Java (GAE/J) version 1.8.7
Java version:     ? [GAE/J dictated]
Java run-time:    ? [GAE/J dictated]
Operating system: ? [GAE/J dictated]
```

**Development**

```
Web server:       Google App Engine app dev server for Java version 1.8.7
Java version:     1.7.0_45; Java HotSpot Client VM 24.45-b08
Java run-time:    Java SE Runtime Environment 1.7.0_45-b18
Operating system: Microsoft Windows XP Home Edition version 2002 SP3 running on x86
```

**For both production and development**

```
Web framework:    Apache Wicket 6.12.0
```

### Example stack trace extract from GAE/J in production

```
org.apache.wicket.DefaultExceptionMapper internalMap: Unexpected error occurred
org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ComponentNotFoundException: Could not find component 'frmForm:enclFound:lvImageDetails:5:imgImage' on page 'class [...].PageImage
at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.PageAndComponentProvider.getComponent(PageAndComponentProvider.java:182)
at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.getComponent(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:90)
at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.respond(ListenerInterfaceRequestHandler.java:231)
at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:861)
at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerStack.execute(RequestHandlerStack.java:64)
at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:261)
at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:218)
at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequestAndDetach(RequestCycle.java:289)
at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:259)
at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:201)
at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:282)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125)
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by rolling back the version of the Apache Wicket web framework used from `6.12.0` to `6.11.0`.

I do not know why this action solved the problem, but it did.